# bluetoothsocket.connect() throws exception in the second run

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I created an Android app to connect to Arduino via bluetooth serial adapter, when I run the app it works fine the first time, after that the bluetoothsocket.connect() throws an exception, the code as follows:-
socket connection:

```
mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
mmSocket.connect();
// send data
mmSocket.close();
```

I don't know where is the problem

Comment: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll  android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt  android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect  PhoneStateReceiver.openBT  onCallStateChanged  handleMessage  dispatchMessage

Comment: edit your answer and add the full stack trace. with formatting

Comment: @Salman I couldn't add as a comment, so I added as an answer

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35527823/edit) your question at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the problem was bluetoothsocket.close();
I should not call this function

Answer (score 0):

You should close the socket only when you are sent all data and no need send anymore, if you need send more data, reconfigure the socket before connect again